# How do I access "Details" ("Title", "Subject", etc.) of file properties in Perl or PowerShell script

Tags: perl, powershell, file-properties

If one looks at file properties in Windows Explorer, the "Details" tab, - for many filetypes (for example, tiff or jpeg images, Office documents, etc.) there is the "Description" section with fields like "Title", "Subject", "Tags", and "Comments". Is there a way to read/write these fields from Perl or a PowerShell script?

Comment: Look here: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/c3d0ea6c-64a1-4716-a262-bcd71c9925fc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PowerShell has gone through some iterations, and this can now be achieved with a native command: **Get-ItemProperty**

Example: Shows the current details of ntdll.dll file:

```
Get-ItemProperty C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll | format-list
```

Comment: this does not provide the extended attributes for certain file types :( how do i get the extended attributes?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote up a [blog post on how to access extended properties](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2005/12/10/msh-get-extended-properties-of-a-file/) a while back - as in when PowerShell was still in beta and called Microsoft Command Shell (MSH).  :-)  I think it's still a valid approach.

Comment: Keith, thanks for so fast response!
For the moment I did not succeeded to apply your code to modern PowerShell, I will try to dig in more :)

Comment: This blog post from Tobias is more up-to-date: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2011/01/07/organizing-videos-and-music.aspx

Comment: Great! that example works perfectly at least to get the values, so all I needed was the .GetDetailsOf function. And what if I would like also to change values in the file - is there any way to do that? If I understand correctly, in that example fields are just copied from the file to NoteProperty members and will not be saved in the file, right?

Comment: is there still not a one-liner powershell/cmd statement that will allow me to access the extended attributes of a given file type? what i will be doing is spawning an instance of powershell from a nodejs script sooo